# Can I condense multiple class' varible declarations?

Tags: c++

I am making a DnD loot system and have a class

```
class RPGItem
{
public:
    string name, type, rarity, description;
    bool attunement = true;
};
```

I want an array to hold all the independant instances of the class. So that I can pull and print each one based on an interger. However it currently looks horrendous with just five items and wanted to know if I could condense this somehow.

```
    RPGItem StoredItems[5];

    StoredItems[0].name = "Longsword +1";
    StoredItems[0].type = "Weapon";
    StoredItems[0].rarity = "Unncommon";
    StoredItems[0].attunement = false;
    StoredItems[0].description = "You have a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon.";

    StoredItems[1].name = "Amulet of Health";
    StoredItems[1].type = "Wondrous Item";
    StoredItems[1].rarity = "Rare";
    StoredItems[1].attunement = true;
    StoredItems[1].description = "Your Constitution score is 19 while you wear this amulet. It has no effect on you if your Constitution is already 19 or higher without it.";

    StoredItems[2].name = "Dust of Dryness";
    StoredItems[2].type = "Wonderous Item";
    StoredItems[2].rarity = "Uncommon";
    StoredItems[2].attunement = false;
    StoredItems[2].description = "This small packet contains 1d6 + 4 pinches of dust. You can use an action to sprinkle a pinch of it over water. The dust turns a cube of water 15 feet on a side into one marble-sized pellet, which floats or rests near where the dust was sprinkled. The pellet's weight is negligible. Someone can use an action to smash the pellet against a hard surface, causing the pellet to shatterand release the water the dust absorbed. Doing so ends that pellet's magic. An elemental composed mostly of water that is exposed to a pinch of the dust must make a DC 13 Constitution saving throw, taking 10d6 necrotic damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.";

    StoredItems[3].name = "Nine Lives Stealer";
    StoredItems[3].type = "Weapon (any sword)";
    StoredItems[3].rarity = "Very Rare";
    StoredItems[3].attunement = true;
    StoredItems[3].description = "You gain a +2 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon. The sword has 1d8 + 1 charges. If you score a critical hit against a creature that has fewer than 100 hit points, it must succeed on a DC 15 Constitution saving throw or be slain instantly as the sword tears its life force from its body(a construct or an undead is immune). The sword loses 1 charge if the creature is slain. When the sword has no charges remaining, it loses this property.";

    StoredItems[4].name = "Ring of Animal Influence";
    StoredItems[4].type = "Ring";
    StoredItems[4].rarity = "Rare";
    StoredItems[4].attunement = false;
    StoredItems[4].description = "This ring has 3 charges, and it regains 1d3 expended charges daily at dawn. While wearing the ring, you can use an action to expend 1 of its charges to cast one of the following spells:\nAnimal friendship(save DC 13)\nFear(save DC 13), targeting only beasts that have an Intelligence of 3 or lower\nSpeak with animals";
```

This is how I currently print them

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n" << StoredItems[i].name << "\n" << StoredItems[i].type << ", " << StoredItems[i].rarity;
        if (StoredItems[i].attunement == true)
        {
            cout << ", Requires Attunement.";
        }
        cout << "\n" << StoredItems[MagicalItems[i]].description << "\n";
    }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You don't want to assign these values by hand-written? Or you don't want to print them by a for loop? Explain what you want to reduce, condense is not clear for what you (don't)want.

Answer (score 2):

The better "object oriented" way to do this is with a real class, rather than a data class:

```
class RPGItem
{
 public:
   string name, type, rarity, description;
   bool attunement = true;

   RPGItem() {
   }

   RPGItem(string name, string type, string rarity, bool attunement, string description) {
       this->name = name;
       this->type = type;
       this->rarity = rarity;
       this->description = description;
       this->attunement = attunement;
   }
};

int main() 
{
    StoredItems[0] = RPGItem("Longsword +1", "Weapon",
                             "Unncommon", false,
                             "You have a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon.");
    

    StoredItems[1] = RPGItem("Amulet of Health",
                             "Wondrous Item",
                             "Rare",
                             true,
                             "Your Constitution score is 19 while you wear this amulet. It has no effect on you if your Constitution is already 19 or higher without it.");
...
```

Now, the other option is to store the data in a datafile in a YAML or JSON or CSV file or something instead and read them in with a parser.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize your array like this instead :

```cpp
RPGItem StoredItems[5] = {

    {"Longsword +1",
    "Weapon",
    "Unncommon",
    "You have a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon.",
    false},

    {"Amulet of Health",
    "Wondrous Item",
    "Rare",
    "Your Constitution score is 19 while you wear this amulet. It has no effect on you if your Constitution is already 19 or higher without it.",
     true},

    {"Dust of Dryness",
    "Wonderous Item",
    "Uncommon",
    "This small packet contains 1d6 + 4 pinches of dust. You can use an action to sprinkle a pinch of it over water. The dust turns a cube of water 15 feet on a side into one marble-sized pellet, which floats or rests near where the dust was sprinkled. The pellet's weight is negligible. Someone can use an action to smash the pellet against a hard surface, causing the pellet to shatterand release the water the dust absorbed. Doing so ends that pellet's magic. An elemental composed mostly of water that is exposed to a pinch of the dust must make a DC 13 Constitution saving throw, taking 10d6 necrotic damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.",
    false},

    {"Nine Lives Stealer",
    "Weapon (any sword)",
    "Very Rare",
    "You gain a +2 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon. The sword has 1d8 + 1 charges. If you score a critical hit against a creature that has fewer than 100 hit points, it must succeed on a DC 15 Constitution saving throw or be slain instantly as the sword tears its life force from its body(a construct or an undead is immune). The sword loses 1 charge if the creature is slain. When the sword has no charges remaining, it loses this property.",
    true},

    {"Ring of Animal Influence";
    "Ring";
    "Rare";
    "This ring has 3 charges, and it regains 1d3 expended charges daily at dawn. While wearing the ring, you can use an action to expend 1 of its charges to cast one of the following spells:\nAnimal friendship(save DC 13)\nFear(save DC 13), targeting only beasts that have an Intelligence of 3 or lower\nSpeak with animals",
    false}
};
```

And clean up your print loop like this:

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const RPGItem &item)
{
    out << "\n" << item.name << "\n" << item.type << ", " << item.rarity;
    if (item.attunement)
    {
        out << ", Requires Attunement.";
    }
    out << "\n" << item.description << "\n";
    return out;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    cout << StoredItems[i];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what should be changed when there is a new member added in RPGItem?